# Django testing. Status 200 and 302

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

How this work? what is the difference between 302 and 200? What is correctly?

```
def test_thanks_page(self):
    response = self.client.get('/thanks/')
    self.failUnlessEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

And what is difference between:

```
self.failUnlessEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

and

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

Comment: `failUnlessEqual` is a deprecated alias of `assertEqual` - http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases

Answer (score 1):

I believe 302 ("moved temporarily") indicates a redirect to another location (with it's URI coming back with the response), while 200 indicates that you got the resource you asked for in the URI you requested.

The [W3 Status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

For 302: "The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI."

I hope this helped.